# How to avoid "save as" dialogue box for firefox downloads?

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, save-as

I am creating a bulk download functionality for a website. It works great for chrome but the save as dialogue box in Firefox is giving me problem. Since I am downloading a large number of files in a loop, it opens the same number of dialogue box (unless they quickly select the save as for the first download.) Is there a way to work around this problem?

Ideally, I was hoping for an event that fires when save as dialogue is selected or perhaps an easy way to know it the default behavior of my current file type is to "ask every time" or "save as" and prompt the user to change that before the downloads begin. But these features aren't there to the best of my knowledge (correct me if I am wrong).

Just to note here, I don't have access to the server so any type of server-side solution wouldn't work for me. I can't zip the files in client side either since these files can be huge.

Just for refernce, although I don't think it's super helpful here the following is my Downloader class and the method of interest here would be `_saveToDisk()`

```
class Downloader{

  /**
   * 
   * @param {Array<string>} downloadLinks 
   */
  constructor(downloadLinks){
    //downloadConstants
    this.bufferSize =
      downloadConstants.bufferSize
    this.noOfActiveFetchLimit =
      downloadConstants.noOfActiveFetchLimit
    this.fallbackNoOfActiveFetchLimit =
      downloadConstants.fallbackNoOfActiveFetchLimit
    this.downloadInterval =
      downloadConstants.downloadInterval
    this.fallbackDownloadInterval =
      downloadConstants.fallbackDownloadInterval

    this.expectedBufferUsed = 0
    this.noOfActiveFetch = 0
    this.downloadedCount = 0
    this.abortedCount = 0
    this.downloadJobCount =
      downloadLinks?.length ? downloadLinks.length : 0

    this.isDownloadOngoing = false
    this.iteratedOnce = false
    this.lastFiveIsEqual = false
    this.hasSizeInfo = true
    
    this.downloadLinks = downloadLinks ?? []
    this.failedDownloads = {
      retry : [], //with status 0
      errorlog: []  //status >= 400
    }
    this.queue = new DownloadQueue()
    this.lastFive = new LastFive()
    this.lastFiveOnloadedSize = new LastFive()
  }

  _isFallBack(){
    return (
    this.expectedBufferUsed > this.bufferSize ||
    !this.hasSizeInfo &&
    (
      !this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.getAvgSize() ?
      true :
      this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.getAvgSize() > this.bufferSize
    ))
  }

  _isDownloadComplete(){
    return (this.downloadedCount + this.abortedCount
      === this.downloadJobCount)
  }

  _shouldAbort(size){
    return (this.bufferSize - this.expectedBufferUsed <= size &&
    !this.iteratedOnce &&
    !this.lastFiveIsEqual &&
    !this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.allEqual())
  }

  _getNoOfActiveFetchLimit(){
    return !this._isFallBack() ?
      this.noOfActiveFetchLimit : this.fallbackNoOfActiveFetchLimit
  }

  _getDownloadInterval(){
    return !this._isFallBack() ?
      this.downloadInterval : this.fallbackDownloadInterval
  }

  _addExpectedBufferUsed(size){

    if (!size){
      if(this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.allEqual()){
        size = this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.array[4]
      }else if(this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.getAvgSize()){
       size = this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.getAvgSize()
      }else{
        size = 0
      }
    }

    this.expectedBufferUsed += size

    //for cases when size info isn't available
    if(this.expectedBufferUsed < 0){
      this.expectedBufferUsed = 0
    }
  }

  _abortHandler(xhr, downloadLink, size){
     //if lastFive elements have same size
      //we assume that all the requests will be the same
      //until proven differently

      xhr.abort()
      this.queue.push({
        url: downloadLink,
        size
      })
      this.lastFive.push(size)      
      this.abortedCount++
      this.noOfActiveFetch--
      return
  }

  _requestSmallerFile(){
    if(this.noOfActiveFetch >= this._getNoOfActiveFetchLimit()){
      return false
    }

    const fetchSize = this.bufferSize - this.expectedBufferUsed
    const newRequestItem = this.queue.pop(fetchSize)
    
    if(newRequestItem != undefined){
      this._fetch(newRequestItem.url)
      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  _filterRequests(xhr, downloadLink){
    const size = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-length") ?
      parseInt(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-length")) :
      null

    this.hasSizeInfo = size ? true : false
    
    this.lastFive.push(size)
    this.lastFiveIsEqual = this.lastFive.allEqual()

    if(this._shouldAbort(size)){
      this._abortHandler(xhr, size, downloadLink)
      this._requestSmallerFile()
      return
    }

    this._addExpectedBufferUsed(size)
  }

  _saveToDisk(res, downloadLink){
    this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.push(res.loaded)
  
    const blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(res)
    const a = document.createElement('a')  
    const fileName = downloadLink.substr(downloadLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    
    a.href = blobURL
    a.setAttribute('download', fileName)  
    
    document.body.appendChild(a)  
    a.click()
    
    a.remove()  
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL)
  }

  _updateDownloadParams(loaded){
     //deduct the memory freed here
    this._addExpectedBufferUsed((-1)*loaded)

    this.noOfActiveFetch--
    this.downloadJobCount++
  }

  _handleErrors(xhr, downloadLink){
    const status = xhr.status
    if(status === 0){
      this.failedDownloads.retry.push(downloadLink)
    } else{
      this.failedDownloads.errorlog.push({
        status,
        url: downloadLink
      })
    }
  }

  _retryFailedDownloads(){
    //under construction
  }

  _onload(xhr, res, downloadLink){
    const status = xhr.status
    
    if(status >= 200 && status < 400){
      this._saveToDisk(xhr.response, downloadLink)
      this._updateDownloadParams(res.loaded)
    } else {
      this._handleErrors(xhr, downloadLink)
    }

    if(this._isDownloadComplete()){
      this._retryFailedDownloads()
    }
  }

  _fetch(downloadLink){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.overrideMimeType('application/octet-stream')

    xhr.onreadystatechange = res => {

      const readyState = xhr.readyState
      
      if (readyState === 1){
        this.fetchCount += 1
        this.noOfActiveFetch += 1
        return
      } else if (readyState === 2){
        this._filterRequests(xhr, downloadLink)
      } else if (readyState === 3){
        return
      } else if (readyState === 4){
        this._onload(xhr, res, downloadLink)
      }
  
    }
    
    xhr.open('GET', downloadLink)
    xhr.responseType = 'blob'
    xhr.send(null)
  }

  _initiateSecondDownloadIteration(){
    this.iteratedOnce = true  
    if (this.queue.length == 0){
      return
    }
    this.downloadLinks = this.downloadLinks.concat(this.queue.getURLs())
    this.queue.reset()
    this._initiateDownload()
    return
  }

  _initiateDownload(){
    
    const setDownloadInterval = () => {
      if (this.downloadLinks.length === 0){
        this._initiateSecondDownloadIteration()
        return
      }

      if(this.noOfActiveFetch >= this._getNoOfActiveFetchLimit()){
        setTimeout(setDownloadInterval,
          this._getDownloadInterval() + this.fallbackDownloadInterval)
        return
      }
  
      this._fetch(`${fileServerBaseUrl}/${directoryEndpoint}/${this.downloadLinks.pop()}`)
      setTimeout(setDownloadInterval, this._getDownloadInterval())
    }
    setTimeout(setDownloadInterval, 0)
  }

  /**
   * 
   * @param {Array.<string>} downloadLinks 
   */
  download(downloadLinks){
    if(downloadLinks != undefined){
      this.downloadLinks = this.downloadLinks.concat(downloadLinks)
      this.downloadJobCount +=
        this.downloadLinks?.length ? downloadLinks.length : 0
    }
    
    if(!this.isDownloadOngoing){
      this.isDownloadOngoing = true
      this._initiateDownload()
      return
    }

    return
  }

   _reset(){
    this.expectedBufferUsed = 0
    this.noOfActiveFetch = 0

    this.downloadedCount = 0
    this.abortedCount = 0
    this.downloadJobCount = 0
    
    this.isDownloadOngoing = false
    this.iteratedOnce = false
    this.lastFiveIsEqual = false
    this.hasSizeInfo = true
    
    this.downloadLinks = []
    this.failedDownloads = {
      retry : [],
      errorlog: []
    }
    this.queue.reset()
    this.lastFive.reset()
    this.lastFiveOnloadedSize.reset()
  }

}
```

Comment: Go to the firefox settings and search for download. There should be checkbox for "Always ask you where to save files", deselect it and choose a fixed location instead.

Comment: @Simon I am not talking about the dialogue box that asks for download location. I am talking about the dialogue box that asks whether to open or save a downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on the Options page to "Ask me every time" where to save your download just set it to **"Never"**.

Comment: I checked that out. The options page will only show the file formats that have already been downloaded once. And the user can't add any new file formats in the list.